# How use $.ajax download JSON from HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a script and this script use AJAX for get JSON

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,   /*url = index.html or data.json, many page use 1 script*/
                success: getData
        });
```

And I have a HTML page with

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">
</script>
```

Script doesn't work with this index.html, but other JSON file work

Comment: Please put your ajax script and the data it is fetching as well. A sample is sufficient

Comment: Why do I put the cons? 
This site unwelcoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $.ajax, there is another parameter called `dataType`. You can specify it to either `json` or `html`. For your script to work, you need a dataType of `html`.

If you do not specify anything, by default it takes `text`.

Also I'm not sure whether it is

```
<script type="application/json"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```